# Compare query results against integer in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written following query.

```
  IF ( select count(*) 
        from source_table 
       where id=Code 
         and to_date(start_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') <= sysdate 
         and to_date(end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')>=sysdate)>0 
  THEN
    checkWithinDateTime:=1;
  END IF;
```

every time i try to execute my procedure, it shows error on if condition.

Comment: Please [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You get a syntax error because the PL/SQL language has no such construction. You probably need to use `select into` to populate a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not check the result of a query that way; you need a variable to handle the result of the query:

```
SQL> begin
  2      if (select count(1) from dual) = 1 then
  3          dbms_output.put_line('One');
  4      else
  5          dbms_output.put_line('Not one');
  6      end if;
  7  end;
  8  /
    if (select count(1) from dual) = 1 then
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:[...]
```

You need instead:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vCount number;
  3  begin
  4      select count(1)
  5      into vCount
  6      from dual;
  7      if vCount = 1 then
  8          dbms_output.put_line('One');
  9      else
 10          dbms_output.put_line('Not one');
 11      end if;
 12  end;
 13  /
One

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```